# Change font-family sweetAlert2 vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, sweetalert2

Hi im trying to change the font of the sweetalert items, quoting from the official docs:

> // style.scss
>
> @import '~sweetalert2/src/variables';
>
> $swal2-background: #990000;
>
> @import '~sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2';

I have a scss folder which contains a file called variables.scss which I use to change some vuetify default values, such as the font. But when it comes to sweetalert I cant manage to change it.

Comment: actually i did the same. created a scss file, imported my variable.scss and `~sweetalert2/src/variables` and `~sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2` . then changed some colors like `$swal2-success: $theme_color_success;` and also font-family and direction of `.swal2-popup` and everything worked for me. but just recently i saw that it only changed `font-family` and `direction` on `local` and just `direction` on server